# How to recusively replace string by regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, replace, match, regular-language

I am looking for some way to replace string by regex in Java for case as below:

```
(BatteryTemperature > 12.23)
```

What I need to do is replace the 12.23 to 54.01, actually is Celsius to Fahrenheit degree as below:

```
(BatteryTemperature > 54.01)
```

However, the string may be different condition like:

```
(Signal = 90) AND (BatteryTemperature > 12.23)
```

or

```
(Signal = 90) OR (Latitude = 123.653) AND (BatteryTemperature > 12.23)
```

I have regex as below

```
(\\((\\w+) (>|<|=) (\\d+.\\d+)\\))
```

However, the regex (?R) seems not support in java?

Did there any other way to replace the BatteryTemperature value by converted one.

```
(Signal = 90) OR (Latitude = 123.653) AND (BatteryTemperature > 54.01)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Regular expressions have nothing to do with temperature conversions

Comment: Java replaceAll method accept regular expression. But if you use above regex, be careful that it will not only replace your BatteryTemperature but also Signal and Latitude. `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29`

Comment: Hi Andremoniy, have edit my typo. I am looking for some way to replace the value of BatteryTemperature item by converted one. Temperature conversions will calculating by another code, instead of using regex

Comment: Hi  Min Naing Oo, thanks for your suggestion. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my question by replaceAll() and Pattern, but not quite sure if there has another way better then this.

```
        String sample = "(Signal = 90) OR (Latitude = 123.653) AND (BatteryTemperature > 54.01)"        
        String key = "BatteryTemperature";
        String[] array = sample.split(" AND | OR ");
        for(String tmp :array)
        {
            System.out.println("String: " + tmp);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(("+key+") (>|<|=) (-?\\d+.\\d*)\\)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tmp);
            if(matcher.find())
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++)
                {
                    if(matcher.group(i).equals(key))
                    {
                        sample = sample.replaceAll(matcher.group(i-1), key + " " + matcher.group(i+1) + " " + convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(matcher.group(i+2)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too complex. You are asking for not straight solution. First IMHO try find indexOf of text like `BatteryTemperature >`. Then you should check if after this index, there is string text similar to any digits sequence. Here you can use regex to find out that or use [TextUtils.isDigitsOnly()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). When you find digits, you can quite easily convert it from C to F.

Try split your problem to smaller pieces.